# My react-joyride component breaks when I try to focus on a component below

Tags: reactjs

I use react-joyride in my code editor component with react-syntax-highlighter. When I select the line with id 'line-60' in the joyride step, my joyride component comes from below and needs to scroll to line 60 because the first line number is 1 when the code editor component opens. However, when the Joyride component scrolls, I have the problem of not focusing properly and scrolling from bottom to top. How can I fix this, thank you.

Starting at line 1, when the Code editor component opens and my joyride step is focused on line 60.

[first photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8VCs.png)

[second photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUPOX.png)

[third photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgUDV.png)

My Joyride component is here:

```
    <Joyride
          run={isRunning}
          continuous
          scrollToFirstStep
          steps={highlightSteps}
          scrollOffset={150}
          callback={handleJoyrideCallback}
          locale={{
            back: t('back'),
            close: t('close'),
            last: t('last'),
            next: t('next'),
            skip: t('skip'),
            open: t('open'),
          }}
          styles={{
            overlay: {
              maxHeight: '100% !important',
              height: '100%',
            },
            options: {
              width: 600,
              overlayHeight: `100%`,
              zIndex: 10000,
              backgroundColor: theme.palette.customColors.bodyBg,
            },
            tooltipContainer: {
              color: theme.palette.text.primary,
              padding: '1rem',
            },
            buttonNext: {
              backgroundColor: 'transparent',
              border: '1px solid ' + theme.palette.primary.main,
              padding: '0.1875rem 0.8125rem',
              borderRadius: 4,
              color: theme.palette.primary.main,
              marginLeft: '0.25rem',
            },
            buttonBack: {
              backgroundColor: 'transparent',
              border: '1px solid ' + theme.palette.primary.main,
              padding: '0.1875rem 0.8125rem',
              borderRadius: 4,
              color: theme.palette.primary.main,
            },
            buttonClose: {
              backgroundColor: 'transparent',
              borderRadius: 4,
              color: theme.palette.primary.main,
            },
            buttonSkip: {
              backgroundColor: 'transparent',
              padding: '0.1875rem 0.8125rem',
              borderRadius: 4,
              color: theme.palette.primary.main,
            },
            beaconInner: {
              animation: 'joyride-beacon-inner 1.2s infinite ease-in-out',
              backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
              borderRadius: '50%',
              display: 'block',
              height: '50%',
              left: '50%',
              opacity: 0.7,
              position: 'absolute',
              top: '50%',
              transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
              width: '50%',
            },
            beaconOuter: {
              animation: 'joyride-beacon-outer 1.2s infinite ease-in-out',
              backgroundColor: hexToRGBA(theme.palette.primary.main, 0.2),
              border: `2px solid ${theme.palette.primary.main}`,
              borderRadius: '50%',
              boxSizing: 'border-box',
              display: 'block',
              height: '100%',
              left: 0,
              opacity: 0.9,
              position: 'absolute',
              top: 0,
              transformOrigin: 'center',
              width: '100%',
            },
          }}
          spotlightClicks={true}
        />
```